# Laravel many to one eager loading only loads first instance

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a many to one relationship between *timeslot* and *room* set up like this:

**room class**

```
class room extends Model
{
    function timeslot()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(timeslot::class);
    }
}
```

**timeslot class**

```
class timeslot extends Model
{
    function room()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(room::class,'room_id','id');
    }
}
```

I want to eager-load all the timeslots and their corresponding rooms. I am using:

```
App\timeslot::with('room')->get()
```

However, if a room is used by two timeslots, only the first instance of the room is loaded. What I want is to have is for the full details of the room to be included in each instance of the timeslot. This is the output I am getting:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#866
     all: [
       App\timeslot {#859
         id: 1,
         slot-count: 1,
         created_at: "2018-02-25 07:30:02",
         updated_at: "2018-02-25 07:30:02",
         day_id: 1,
         group_id: null,
         room_id: null,
         room: null,
       },
       App\timeslot {#858
         id: 2,
         slot-count: 2,
         created_at: "2018-02-25 07:30:02",
         updated_at: "2018-02-25 07:30:02",
         day_id: 1,
         group_id: null,
         room_id: null,
         room: null,
       },
       App\timeslot {#857
         id: 3,
         slot-count: 3,
         created_at: "2018-02-25 07:30:02",
         updated_at: "2018-02-25 07:30:02",
         day_id: 1,
         group_id: 2,
         room_id: 1,
         room: App\room {#870
           id: 1,
           name: "A108",
           created_at: "2018-02-25 07:30:02",
           updated_at: "2018-02-25 07:30:02",
         },
       },
       App\timeslot {#856
         id: 4,
         slot-count: 4,
         created_at: "2018-02-25 07:30:02",
         updated_at: "2018-02-25 07:30:02",
         day_id: 1,
         group_id: 3,
         room_id: 1,
         room: App\room {#870},
       },
     ],
   }
```

It is possible that this is not a bug, but a feature!

Is there a way to modify the query (I have simplified it as I also want to get the groups - but will apply the same solution to both) to repeat the room information with each instance?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on how would would like the result to look? Its not clear to me what you mean when you say the full details. That second room for timeslot #856 is a full room instance.

Comment: The second room instance just says {#870} and doesn't (seem to have) all the other details, such as name.

Comment: I'm 90% sure that is just `dd` or whatever you are using to print your results. That object should be a full object if you were to key into it.

Comment: I'm looking at the output from tinker but I get the same result if I use dd or dump. I shall loop through and see if the data is actually there. You may well be right!

Comment: Can a one timeslot be in only one room, or one timeslot can corespond to many rooms?

Comment: Each timeslot can have only one room. However, each room can be allocated to many timeslots. So one to many but, i'm reading it in reverse, ie fetching the timeslot and getting the room data.

Comment: @RobAnthony was it not a full object? I'm very curious.

Comment: It was all there, you were quite right that the issue was with the dump function. If you put it as an answer, I will credit you.